# Show created users for every day

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to count how many users were created for every day last week. I created something like this:

```
users = User.where(created_at: (Time.now - 7.day)..Time.now)
users.group_by{|p| p.created_at.at_beginning_of_day}.each do |day, array|
   puts "on #{day} #{array.size}"
end
```

I want to output to be:

```
on Sun 29
on Mon 34
etc.
```

but instead of that I get this:

```
{Sun, 25 Aug 2013 00:00:00 CEST +02:00=>[#<User id: 10, email: "jssdc@ssds.cz", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$QWz7p86JAURxvWJj8GZFm.o2a589y7T4htcOJyUqe4aK...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2013-08-25 12:30:05", updated_at: "2013-08-25 12:30:40", authentication_token: "ytMoqBwRHVZseN7bbsvU", confirmation_token: "fuWEN7DGhC6XpRqtSpWR", confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: "2013-08-25 12:30:05", unconfirmed_email: nil>], Tue, 27 Aug 2013 00:00:00 CEST +02:00=>[#<User id: 11, email: "bz@sefdsa.cz", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$4ZZq58B.az9vZ1TFaNVkVeN7PyLRogKEilpV8VvXFY1u...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2013-08-27 21:44:06", updated_at: "2013-08-27 21:44:06", authentication_token: "A1MPhxUQLsPDNSo25xUK", confirmation_token: "sipxKTmuNNvnp4RePsYd", confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: "2013-08-27 21:44:06", unconfirmed_email: nil>], Wed, 28 Aug 2013 00:00:00 CEST +02:00=>[#<User id: 12, email: "fdsafdas@sfdsa.cz", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$y/RGxp5dpwq.jpV2d9HTAOLgLFjqgtJnS6IWpFyFwxLj...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2013-08-27 23:00:43", updated_at: "2013-08-27 23:00:43", authentication_token: "UE9ty2K5EoRgm4oveMhf", confirmation_token: "a7186dyyyVNMyBpTpJ6k", confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: "2013-08-27 23:00:43", unconfirmed_email: nil>, #<User id: 13, email: "madafaka@lol.cz", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$2yDV5KNs3JMpP.OJ/f6rQOgu6P6DFS/Xoc33eYtlAJ6z...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2013-08-27 23:58:51", updated_at: "2013-08-27 23:58:51", authentication_token: "fieiR4ZJ9y9PWux82CLq", confirmation_token: "9ujvWvbvnubyZWisM4sy", confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: "2013-08-27 23:58:51", unconfirmed_email: nil>]}
```

How can I output the created users every day for last week in the desired format?

Comment: Are you doing this in `irb`? If so, add `; nil` to the end of each line to avoid unwanted output.

Comment: Your code works. Like @AlexD says, if you're doing this in irb it will print the result of `users.group_by{|p| p.created_at.at_beginning_of_day}` after doing your `puts`, so you may have lost it somewhere. You can use `.maps` or do as suggested previously to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
User.group("date(created_at)").count
```

You will get output like

```
{"2013-08-27"=>1, "2013-08-13"=>2, "2013-08-19"=>2}
```

For getting the count for just one week you can do,

```
User.where("created_at > ?", 7.days.ago).group("extract(dow from created_at)").count
```

This will give you output like

```
{"2" => 2, "0" => 1}
```

"0" is sunday, "1" is monday and so on

Comment: i mean its {"2013-08-25"=>1, "2013-08-27"=>3} this output instead of my i want to like each doesnt work!

Comment: Modified the answer. You can easily map 0, 1, 2.. to the day of the week whereever you want to display

Comment: but it look like the .each doesnt work, beacuse i do puts and nothing happend and there is still {"2013-08-27"=>1, "2013-08-13"=>2, "2013-08-19"=>2}

Comment: `{"2" => 2, "0" => 1}.each {|key, value| puts key; puts value}`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: well yes, like users.each {|key, value| puts key; puts value} .. but it show still the {"2" => 2, "0" => 1}

Comment: and if i try:
{"2" => 2, "0" => 1}.each {|key, value| puts key; puts value}
i again get only {"2" => 2, "0" => 1} like .each doesnt even exist :D

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL this will probably work:

```
User.where(created_at: 7.days.ago..Time.now)
  .group("LEFT(DAYNAME(created_at), 3)").count.each do |day, count|
    puts "on #{day}: #{count}"
end
```

Comment: im using postgsql :/ but its almost same like my first try

Comment: i mean its {"2013-08-25"=>1, "2013-08-27"=>3} this output instead of my i want to like each doesnt work!